# Can't reset FormBuilder()

Tags: flutter

i have a FormBuilder() which contains :

- FormBuilderChoiceChip()
- 2 FormBuilderTextField()
- and a Confirm and reset buttons

When i press the reset button, it resets only FormBuilderChoiceChip(), and when i removed it it works (resets the 2 FormBuilderTextFields).

I tried replacing FormBuilderChoiceChip() by a FormBuilderDropDown(), same thing.

reset function :

```
void _reset() {
    _formKey.currentState.reset();
}
```

flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder is a package that is not native to Flutter. I can see that you've already reported this issue in their GitHub page https://github.com/danvick/flutter_form_builder/issues/263 Unless you want to manually reset the fields yourself outside of the package, then you will need to wait for their feedback.

Comment: OK, and how can i manually reset the fields ?

Comment: I would use the standard `Chip` provided by Flutter and reset it myself. You haven't showed us your code, so we don't know how you are using the Chips, but you should be able to do it.

Comment: Well, i tried the standard DropDownButton, and it didn't work either